# Coarsened Exact Matching Non Homogeneous Treatment Effects

Tags: r, model, random-forest, matching

I am using the coarsened exact matching (CEM) package in R. I'm trying to understand the non-homogenous treatment effects.

I've attached what an image of the linear model looks like and the model with random effects. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtYzt.png)The package also use allows you to use the random forest option.[Linear Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtYzt.png) [Random forest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdZCM.png)

But how does one interpret the output? The random forest and effects models look the same as the output for the linear model (different values). How do I know what the different treatment effects are for different values of the other variable? They also offer a way to plot the SATT, but I think that's for the linear model and I also am confused on how to interpret that.

The link to the guide is here: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/cem.pdf

Answer (score 0):

"Homogeneous treatment effect" refers to an *assumption* that the treatment effect is the same for all units, i.e., it does not depend on other factors. "Non-homogeneous treatment effect" allows that the treatment effect might differ across units. Certain methods of estimating the treatment effect are only compatible with a homogeneous treatment effect. If that assumption is incorrect, then the estimate will be biased. Other methods are compatible with either a homogeneous or non-homogeneous treatment effect and can be used in either scenario.

If the treatment effect is indeed homogeneous, then your estimate will be more precise if you use a method for homogeneous treatment effects. In general, though, this is a bad assumption to make, so you should generally use a method that is compatible with both homogenous or non-homogeneous treatment effects, such as the random forest or linear-RE methods. (That is, it's worse to assume a homogeneous treatment effect and be wrong than it is to assume a non-homogeneous treatment effect and be wrong.)

Even if the treatment effect is estimated as non-homogeneous, the `att` function estimates the **average treatment effect**, which is the average of the individual treatment effects (which are allowed to vary with the models compatible with non-homogeneous treatment effects). This is why the output looks the same regardless of which assumption you make: you are estimating the same single quantity but under one assumption or another.